# AJAX update breaking new form

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a web page that is used to upload files to a server.  The site works if when a student logs in, the default class is displayed. If the student needs to upload a file for another class, the students selects the new class from a drop down and part of the page, including the form upload, is rewritten using AJAX, the form no longer will upload the file.  Instead of the upload div refreshing, the whole page refreshes and the file is not uploaded

Form Code

```
   <form id='010101' data-url='student.asp?M=20&A=01' data-pageelement='010101' method='post'    >
    <input id='i2' type='file' name='myFile' />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>
```

I've tried deleting the old form before I write the new form with

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("FORM");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
   var gone=all[i];
   gone.parentNode.removeChild(gone);
}
```

to see if that helps, but it did not.

I think I'm missing a major detail on how HTML pages work.

Comment: As far as I understood the problem is that page reloads after form submit or what?

Comment: Whatever library you're using to do your file upload -- those event listeners are gone when you replace the form with data received via AJAX. Think of it this way: you attach a click listener to a `button`, but then remove and re-add that button. The listener is gone and must be reattached. That's basically what you're doing. You have to figure out how to reinitialize your form upload code or possibly just update the data attributes instead of replacing the entire element. If you expand on what libraries and surrounding code you have, we can help you further.

Comment: ^ To expand on that, I'm assuming from your `data-` attributes that you have some library in place, since those aren't default HTML form props. The default action of an HTML form (with no JS) is to submit to another page (redirect) and JS has to stop that. So by losing your `submit` event handler (assuming, again) the form reverts to its native HTML behavior and redirects. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: well the code when run in a snipplet on stackoverflow works so not sure what your issue is. The form is removed. If it is removed, than your issue is with code you have not shared with us.